# passing data between controller methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, ienumerable

I'm creating asp.net mvc 5 application. in this application I have faced to problem passing data between controller methods.

Here the scenario step by step

1. I'm getting `IEnumerable` dataset to `Create_Brochure` method like this

   ```
   public ActionResult Create_Brochure(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model)
   {

       IEnumerable<BrochureTemplateProperties> sample = model.Where....

       return View(sample);
   }
   ```

   [image]
2. Then I need to save that `IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model` to another `IEnumerable` object and use that in `Create_Brochure_PDF()` method

   ```
   public ActionResult Create_Brochure_PDF()
   {

       IEnumerable<BrochureTemplateProperties> samplePDF = modelPDF....

       return View(samplePDF);
   }
   ```

for that I'did bit R&D part and came up solution with **Sessions** , Here [the tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576514/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusVariousplus) I followed

So I changed my code like this

but seems I'm having compile time errors though I followed exact as tutorial

1st controller method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create_Brochure(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model)
    {
        IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> modelPDF = new IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM>();

        modelPDF = model;

       IEnumerable<BrochureTemplateProperties> sample = model.Where(y => y.IsChecked)
               .Select(y => new BrochureTemplateProperties
               {
                   Property_ID = y.Property_ID,
                   IsChecked = y.IsChecked,
                   Property_Title = y.Property_Title,
                   Property_Value = y.Property_Value
               });

        TempData["TemplateData"] = modelPDF;

        return View(sample);
    }
```

2nd controller method

```
    public ActionResult Create_Brochure_PDF()
    {

        IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> modelPDF = TempData["TemplateData"] as IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM>;

        IEnumerable<BrochureTemplateProperties> samplePDF = modelPDF.Where(y => y.IsChecked)
                .Select(y => new BrochureTemplateProperties
                {
                    Property_ID = y.Property_ID,
                    IsChecked = y.IsChecked,
                    Property_Title = y.Property_Title,
                    Property_Value = y.Property_Value
                });

        return View(samplePDF);
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @StephenMuecke `Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not instantiate interface..!

Replace

```
IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> modelPDF = new IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM>();
modelPDF = model;
```

With

```
IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> modelPDF = model;
```

inside your `Create_Brochure` method.

Comment: do I need to use `modelPDF = model;` also

Comment: @kez You can remove that as there would be no meaning of that then after.

Comment: Here I'm getting null object noh

Comment: If I explain whole scenario this 1. `Create_Brochure` controller has a view  , 2. In that view I have href link to save that Create_Brochure view as PDF 3.Once I click that link I'm calling `PrintIndex` method so in that action method again its calling to `Create_Brochure_PDF` method , so I'm getting null object set in `Create_Brochure_PDF` method here the relavant code snippets https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/xLXjr